# How can I improve this downvoted question?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, asking-questions, downvote-reason

I'm working to make my questions better and with my latest I have made sure I conformed to the whole outline. I think my question is good, but for some reason I still received downvotes. I'm not sure whether I made a mistake in asking my question or if my question was just too obvious (it wasn't to me), but I genuinely want to improve my questions and it would be very helpful if you could give me some pointers. Thanks for the help ahead of time!

Here's my question: [How to fix go build error "can't load package" with go modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56839174/how-to-fix-go-build-error-cant-load-package-with-go-modules?noredirect=1)

Comment: That question does have 2 close votes for *This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.* and if that is true it is unlikely to be seen as useful for future visitors. That is a down vote reason. I don't do go so I can't really judge if this is a trivial error that was easy to diagnose but based on what I see I would agree it isn't a question that will help many visitors to come.

Comment: Ok,  thanks for the info so now I understand that this was a simple question (I was unaware of that when I wrote it) but is there any way to ask questions on SO where I miss something that most do not? Is there any way I could improve this question or ask it better? How could I improve for next time? @rene

Comment: I give you it doesn't look like the low quality stuff I normally see. It might be that the Go tag is a bit stricter on what they appreciate. A bit like when you tag your question with C and C++, it needs to be an awesome question in that case.

Comment: Hmm ok... I'm just not sure what I can do about it. Any ideas @rene ?

Comment: [Avoid the "How to ... ?" construct](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56625).

Comment: I think the question is fine and is well-written. That Stack Overflow supports a policy of down-voting questions discourages liberal use of the services, encourages bad actors and serves an unclear purpose when there's limitless ability to persist these questions and minor impact on searchability. This appears to promote arbitrary (per tag) policies (as exampled) and promote intolerance.

Answer (score -11):

I've also experienced multiple times that somehow Go questions tend to attract a large mass of unfair downvotes. Check, for example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45818964/1783163) of mine.

Furthermore, also the reactions I've got (in the form of comments and crap/unfair close reasons) have clearly shown, that we have some inherent problem with our Go sub-community. My impression is that they are interested in to expel other developers from Go projects, and not to create an useful set of Go questions/answers for the site.

The correct handling of the problem would probably require some CM intervention. It can't be solved on the moderator level, because it would require direct access to the individual votes. It is very unlikely, so the case probably remains as it was. Maybe time can solve it - if enough developers will be active in Go topics, their votes can compensate this hiding herd.

Until then, a possible workaround is to use alternate accounts for Go questions.

<sub>(BTW, I found Go very useful to develop complex algorithms quickly. But it is nowhere to Java, C++ or anything for practical tasks. I think it is a failed experiment of the Google. I don't think that you would lose too much if you would go to an other direction. For roughly the same goals, I would suggest to try [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/).)</sub>

Comment: Go *is* used in production (though it can be extremely memory hungry).

Comment: *Note: you are free to vote the answer down, if you disagree, but voting to delete, because you disagree, is a power misuse.*

Comment: @PeterMortensen Yes, I know. I don't say that it is unusable, I only say that it is sub-optimal (and unsuccessful). However, it is only my personal opinion and I honor your opinion if you disagree it.